# getting different response in flutter post request compared to other rest clients

Tags: flutter, dart, post, flutter-http

I'm getting different response from the api if call it using flutter
Response in YARC REST Client:
[image]
[image]
Response in Flutter:
[image]
The first line is the json sent to the api.

The error showm in api log:

```
Failed to parse json data from JsonRpc@::ffff:192.168.0.243: Error: illegal value at Line: 0, Column: 0
```

Main.dart:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/flutter_colorpicker.dart';
import 'package:smart_home/user_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future req(String col) async{
  var data = json.encode({
    "command":"color",
    "color":[255,0,0],
    "priority":50,
    "origin":"My Fancy App"
  });

  print(data);
  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.151:8090/json-rpc"),
      body: data,
      headers: {"Authorization": "token 46a2032e-da1b-4c20-b690-27413aa43589"}
  );
  print(response.body);
  if(response.statusCode==200){
    final String responseString = response.body;
    return userModelFromJson(responseString);
  }
  else
  return null;
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var selectedvalue = null;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Led Controls",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
              child: DropdownButton(
                value: selectedvalue,
                items: <String>['Static color', 'Effects'].map((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedvalue=value.toString();
                  });
                },
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: Text("Select Operating Mode"),
              ),
            ),
            if(selectedvalue=="Static color") Container(
              //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
                child: ColorPicker(
                    pickerColor: Colors.white,
                    paletteType: PaletteType.hueWheel,
                    onColorChanged: (x) async{
                      String col="[${x.red.toString()},${x.green.toString()},${x.blue.toString()}]";
                      final UserModel? resp = await req(col);
                      //print(resp!.success);
                },
                )
            )

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my first flutter project so I'm still not completely sure of how stuff work.

Update:
It is working fine on YARC, postman and python. It is not working on advanced rest client(arc) and flutter.

Comment: You seem to be doing everything right. Any chance you could grab a packet capture (e.g. wireshark) at the server of each request? YARC *may* be adding another header we don't see (e.g. Content-Type). It shouldn't make any difference but you could force the character encoding with `body: utf8.encode(data),`

Comment: Have you tried using Postman?

Comment: It working in postman and python now. I just have to get it working in flutter

Comment: Are we able to test the api as well?

Comment: Nope I didn't create it. It's a software called hyperion running on my raspberry pi.

Comment: What is running this Flutter app? Is it an iOS device/simulator, Android device/emulator, etc?

Comment: Android emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in the Hyperion server. It is treating the HTTP headers as case sensitive. (This violates the relevant RFC.) Dart always forces the headers to lower case. In this case the server is looking for `Content-Length`, but Dart sends `content-length`, which the server (incorrectly) doesn't figure out are the same thing.

Luckily there's a way in Dart to force the case of headers, but you have to write a few more lines of boiler-plate. Here's a working example:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  // encode the post body as JSON and then UTF8 bytes
  final dataBytes = utf8.encode(json.encode({
    'command': 'color',
    'color': [255, 0, 0],
    'priority': 50,
    'origin': 'My Dart App'
  }));

  // use the low level HttpClient to get control of the header case
  final client = HttpClient();
  final request = await client.post('127.0.0.1', 8090, '/json-rpc');
  // manually add the content length header to preserve its case
  request.headers.add(
    'Content-Length', // note the upper case string - try it with lower case (spoiler it fails)
    dataBytes.length.toString(),
    preserveHeaderCase: true,
  );
  // optional - add other headers (e.g. Auth) here
  // request.headers.add(/*some other header*/);
  
  // send the body bytes
  request.add(dataBytes);
  
  // 'close' the request to send it, and get a response
  final response = await request.close();
  print(response.statusCode);

  // turn the streamed response back to a string so that it can be parsed as JSON
  final responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  print(responseBody);
  
  // close the client (or re-use it if you prefer)
  client.close();
}
```

Comment: If you have access to the Hyperion forum, you might want to add to this thread ( https://hyperion-project.org/forum/index.php?thread/10695-help-with-json-control/&postID=36144&highlight=headers#post36144 ) saying that the only header that matters is `Content-Length` (note that one poster suggests incorrectly that no headers should be sent) and that it must be in upper case (this is presumably why ARC fails, but no proof of that).

Comment: thank you so much for your help it works now. I actually lost hope on this and made an api using python to communicate with Hyperion's api.

Comment: I've posted a link to question in Hyperion forum .